Unable to Use Telnet on Ports 25, 465, 587 from Non-Root Users
I am trying to connect to smtp.gmail.com on ports 25, 465, and 587 using telnet. The connection works perfectly when running the command as root, but it fails when attempting the same from any non-root user. The error message I receive is "Network is unreachable."

I have verified that the ports are open, and there are no firewall or iptables restrictions.

The non-root users can ping external IPs and resolve domain names using nslookup.

The issue persists for all non-root users, including those with
elevated permissions via sudo.


What could be causing this restriction for non-root users, and how can I resolve it so they can use telnet on these ports?
Any help would be appreciated!
Edit 1:
For example, running this command will not work:
root@server:~# sudo -u testuser telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 142.250.141.109...
Trying 2607:f8b0:4023:c0b::6c...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

But this will work:
root@server:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 142.250.141.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP d2e1a72fcca58-71ec1407f55sm8209951b3a.203 - gsmtp

Edit 2:
Iptables are not blocking non-root users:
root@server:~# sudo iptables -L -n -v | grep -E 'ACCEPT|DROP|REJECT' | grep 587
 107K 6074K ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:587
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:587
 848K   11G ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
6523K   23G ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587 owner GID match 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587 owner UID match 0
 5064  385K LOGDROPOUT  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587


Please show the actual command you're running where it works, and again where it doesn't.

Check the iptables settings. Is it possible that these ports are blocked for non-root users?

@popey I have updated the question with the actual commands.

@FilipStachowiak Actually I am new to ubuntu, how do I check it? but I know I am using ufw - I am not sure if this is related.

@FilipStachowiak I checked with the help of ChatGPT, and it seems that it's not blocking.

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564

There's a lot wrong with what you're doing. Using sudo when you're already root, for one. Also, do the telnet from the test user, not via root via sudo. Switch to the user, and just run telnet as you have, with no sudo. How is the testuser configured?
